# get xml data from magento through angularjs in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, magento, soap, ionic-framework, soapui

I am very new to `AngularJs` and `Ionic Framework`. I have been given a  [link to `Magento` database](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html) with the user and passkey. But I have no idea on how to get started with it. I came across a library called  [Angular-SOAP](http://mcgivery.com/soap-web-services-angular-ionic/), but not getting any idea on how to go with it. Please help.